# How to get client IP address with WebSocket (websockets/ws) library in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I cannot find the client IP parameter on the client object.

Answer (score 83):

After a bit of messing around trying to figure out which one gives the client (web browser's) IP address, the answer is:

```
ws._socket.remoteAddress
```

Or if you have access to `req` via `wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {})`:

```
req.socket.remoteAddress
```

You can use this, for example, to GeoIP locate where the user is connecting from.

**Edit:**

If you're running Node behind an Nginx reverse proxy (or any other reverse proxy for that matter), you may need to use:

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.socket.remoteAddress
```

*A note on security: If your Node server is available directly as well as through the reverse proxy, you might like to check the `remoteAddress` before trusting `x-forwarded-for`. The remote address should be your reverse proxy's IP. There's the odd chance someone could call your service directly and spoof `x-forwarded-for`.*

Comment: Just to be pedantic - edit applies to all reverse proxies, not just nginx (lots of people use haproxy)

Comment: Hmmm that is odd, when displaying socket.upgradeReq.connection in the console, the remoteAddress field is hidden, any idea why?  It took me forever to find the users IP. Thank you Chris Nolet! :)

Comment: It's shocking how all of these web socket API's differ so much.  So much potential, yet so fragmented.

Comment: Checkout the `forwarded-for` library in npm which does this all automatically for you for most of the reverse proxies and ip address information on Node's sockets as it has changed quite a few times.

Comment: @ChrisNolet Where do you get `req` from.  My code is: `const server = new websocket.Server(conf.ws); server.on('connection', (ws) => { ...`.

Comment: @fadedbee req is provided as the second parameter in the case of the `connection` event: `server.on('connection', (ws, req) => { ..`, see https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#event-connection

Answer (score 30):

Got this from printing the keys in the socket object:

```
> ws._socket.address()
  { port: 8081,
    family: 2,
    address: '127.0.0.1' }

> ws._socket.remoteAddress
  '74.125.224.194'

> ws._socket.remotePort
  41435
```

I don't have any documentation so I'm not sure how well this is supported across versions :/

Answer (score 6):

In websocket server, since `req.connection` is deprecated, you use `req.socket`.

```
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    console.log(req.socket.remoteAddress);
});
```