# Why is remoteAddress hidden?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm using Node.js with https://github.com/websockets/ws.

I'm trying to store the users remoteAddress in a temporary socket variable. I can access this variable by:
`socket.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress`

The problem is, where in the world did remoteAddress come from? The variable 'remoteAddress' is not even found in any of the WS node_plugin files in the lib directory. (I used Notepad++ to search through every file.)

The only reason I came about finding access to this variable is from this topic: *[How to get client IP address using websocket (einaros / ws) lib in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822708/how-to-get-client-ip-address-using-websocket-einaros-ws-lib-in-node-js)*

Heck, even when displaying `console.log(self.upgradeReq.connection);` in my console I still cannot find it!

Images of the object console list:

[image]

[image]

Where in the world? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please don't use images, if it's code, just put it in the question directly as a code block.

Comment: Well, I figured all that code in the console would spam the page :P

Comment: If you want people to bother with your question, it needs to be readable though. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: since it's part of the connection, it probably defined by `net` or whatever WS uses...

Comment: I think this is a useful question, even if the format of the question is different.  Inline images would work ( @NiCkNewman ).

Comment: Thanks @blong it's fine. I'll try to keep them less cluttered in  the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes Node.js's built-in `net` module. Here's how to trace it:

The [ws documentation](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md) refer to `upgradeReq` as "The HTTP request that initiated the upgrade". Glancing through the `ws` code makes it clear that it uses Node.js's built-in `http` library for handling HTTP requests.

The Node.js [`http` request documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connection) says that `http.ClientRequest.connection` is a reference to a given request's underlying TCP `socket`.

Node.js's TCP code is in the `net` library. The [`net` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteaddress) document `socket.remoteAddress`.

Comment: Just recovered my email and saw this post, thank you so much. Marked as best.

Okay I see now, I guess I missed that when reading over their docs.